# AndroidAsyncHttp Error

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, braintree, android-async-http

I'm trying to implement the LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp for a Braintree project. I downloaded the .jar file and added it as a library.

I now have the following code:

```
public class PayCharge extends Activity {

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.paycharge);



    client.get("https://xxx.herokuapp.com/generateToken.php", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // Initiated the request
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String clientToken) {
            // Successfully got a response
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String responseBody, Throwable e) {
            // Response failed :(
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Completed the request (either success or failure)
        }



    });

}


}
```

However, the TextHttpResponseHandler() part is underlined red with the following error:
class 'Anonymous class derived from TextHttpResponseHandler()' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onSuccess(int, Header[], string) in TextHttpResponseHandler"

Additionally, both of the onSuccess and onFailure @Override are underlined red claiming that the method does not override from its superclass.

I'm a beginner so not quite sure how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: Just delete the whole `client.get(...)` again and let code  completion do its magic.

Comment: thanks, this works. What do I fill in for the (int i, Header[] headers, String s) parameters for onSuccess/onFailure? s will be clientToken, but the other two?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: i  dont really understand what those parameters are for. the int and header . i read the documentation but am still confused

Answer (score 1):

If keep your code the same as you have in your question and you change your method signature of `onSuccess(String clientToken)` to `onSuccess(int responseCode, Header[] responseHeaders, String responseBody)` the response body will be the String `onSuccess` is called with. This will be your client token from your server.

Comment: unable to get client token from server? i am getting onFailure method while try to get token from server. can you plz give me the code for do how can i do this. please help

Comment: If you're getting the failure callback then you either cannot connect to your server or your server is returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
...

@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

}

...
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining or making your answer more clear.