# Can't override onSuccess() method in JsonHttpResponseHandler

Tags: java, android, rest, asynchttpclient

I am learning restful services in http://www.raywenderlich.com/78578/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-3

while coming across

```
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(QUERY_URL + urlString,
        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
// Display a "Toast" message
// to announce your success
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// 8. For now, just log results
Log.d("omg android", jsonObject.toString());
}      
@Override

public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject  error) {
// Display a "Toast" message 
// to announce the failure
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode + " " +    throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// Log error message
// to help solve any problems
Log.e("omg android", statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage());
}
        });
```

My gradle sync task was successful.But I couldn't figure out that why onSuccess method is enlightened as (Method does not override super class)

Even I have changed the onSuccess() parameters to

```
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, JSONObject jsonObject)
```

and also I have followed all the solutions provided in the following links

[method does not override or implement a method from a supertype - for Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217737/method-does-not-override-or-implement-a-method-from-a-supertype-for-override)

[AndroidAsyncHttp Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809387/android-asynchttpclient-error)

http://answered.site/-heres-my-mainactivityjava-the-part-of-the-code-it-occurs-in-the-querybooks/2950406/

Even I have tried using interfaces also.And I am using async http 1.4.9
So I have changed the gradle scripts as

```
dependencies {

    ...

    // there may or may not be a support library above these
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

I have tried all the solutions available in stackoverflow and github.But still I couldn't clear that error and it is showing me onSuccess() and onFailure() methods doesn't override the superclass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check you imports

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONObject;

**import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;**
```

and try this

```
client.get("sdsd", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
        super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
    }
});
```

You are using the wrong Header and overriding nonexistent methods. I think may be those were available on an old release.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the `onSuccess` function call

```
super.onSuccess();
```

This will fix your error. When you override a method, it is common to also call the original method (the super class's method).

Same for `onFailure`

```
super.onFailure();
```

You can check this [link](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html) to see the parameters of each callback function.

As already mentioned by *@hegazy* you use wrong headers for the functions, the tutorial you followed is most likely outdated. Check the link for all possible functions with correct headers. In the `super` calls you can pass the same variables.

Comment: super calls must be placed at the start, not the end

Comment: @fattidare for future reference, that is not always true. E.g. the `super.onDestroy()` is usually called at the end

Comment: @TimCastelijns Your practice is incorrect. Sometimes you need to put it at the end, but isn't the best way

Answer (score 0):

just use the right header

Try:

```
@Override
public void  onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
   // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode,cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject response) {

}
```